# Allowing user access to analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to enable (some) of my users to view my website's analytics data.

Our website has a bunch of groups where users can add content. I would like to enable certain users (group admins), to view usage statistics for that specific group. Ofcourse the data should only be accessable to those users with the VIEW_ANALYTICS right, not to any others.

Is there any way to do this in Google Analytics, or is there some other platform I could use to easily achieve this goal (we use AWS for our hosting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate view for each group and only give them access to that view. Assuming you only want them to have access to the stats on content that they post you will need to filter those views based on something.

If each user group posts on a particular sub domain or a sub folder ONLY... you can filter using those items.

If not...

You can tag your content using GTM with a simple datalayer that is unique to each group and pass it to GA via Custom Dimension. Then setup your views by filtering the groups in Custom Dimension.

Comment: I will tomorrow, when I'm back at the office

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to provide this information directly on your website and/or app, Google provides [Analytics Reporting APIs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/) that allow you to programmatically access Analytics data.

You might want to check out the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/), or the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/)  for creating and embedding dashboard-style JavaScript reporting widgets.